# private params in launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, parameter, node, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

From what understand about launch file, `<param>` defined in `<node>` are private to that `<node>`. But the behaviour of my launch file doesn't look right to me. Here is the content of the launch file:

```
<arg name="num" default="2"/>                                 
<param name="~num_drones" value="$(arg num)"/>                

 <node name="A" pkg="drone_core" type="drone.py">             
     <param name="local_name_leaked" value="leaked"/>          
 </node>                                

 <node name="B" pkg="drone_simulator" type="sim.py">   
     <param name="local_name" value="debug"/>                  
 </node>
```

Here are what rosparam list returned for A and B

```
/A/local_name_leaked
/A/num_drones       
/B/local_name       
/B/local_name_leaked
/B/num_drones
```

So my question is, why would "local_name_leaked" show up under /B namespace?

I'm using Jade.

Thanks

## ===========================
Update 1

I've narrowed down the cause. I'm reposting the full launch file for clairty

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                          
                                                                
<launch>                                                        
                                                                
    <param name="~num_drones" value="2"/>                       
    <!--param name="num_drones_local" value="2"/-->             
                                                                
    <node name="A" pkg="drone_core" type="drone.py">           
        <param name="local_name_leaked" value="leaked" />       
    </node>                                                     
                                                                
    <node name="B" pkg="drone_simulator" type="sim.py"> 
      <param name="local_name" value="debug"/>                  
    </node>                                                     
                                                                
</launch>
```

With this `<param name="~num_drones" value="2"/>`, I get:

```
PARAMETERS                      
 * /A/local_name_leaked: leaked 
 * /A/num_drones: 2             
 * /B/local_name: debug         
 * /B/local_name_leaked: leaked 
 * /B/num_drones: 2                   
 * /rosdistro: jade             
 * /rosversion: 1.11.21
```

With this `<param name="num_drones_local" value="2"/>` I get:

```
PARAMETERS                       
 * /A/local_name_leaked: leaked  
 * /B/local_name: debug          
 * /num_drones_local: 2          
 * /rosdistro: jade              
 * /rosversion: 1.11.21
```

Notice one has "~num_drones", one has "num_drones".
I was assuming `<param name="~num_drones" value="2"/>` would create private param in any sub sequence declaration of `<node>` block. But is that allowed? It seems to do that, but also cause any parameter declared inside `<node>` block to "leak" to sub sequence `<node>` blocks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283280/private-params-in-launch-file/) by [CodingPeon](https://answers.ros.org/users/29242/codingpeon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-02-21

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-02-21**:
Are you sure these parameters are being set by your launch file? Parameters persist on the roscore, so these might be left over from a previous launch file.
Some nodes also set parameters, so it's possible that node B is setting this parameter.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-02-21**:
roslaunch will print all of the parameters that it will set at startup; you should be able to see it setting (or not setting) this parameter as part of its output.

**Comment by [CodingPeon](https://answers.ros.org/users/29242/codingpeon/) on 2018-02-22**:
Because of character limits in reply box, I've updated the original post with my findings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The roslaunch docs for the [`<param>` tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param) clearly state that this should be possible, so this looks like a bug in roslaunch.

You've provided a great sample that reproduces this already; can you create a ticket on the [ros_comm issue tracket](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues)?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CodingPeon](https://answers.ros.org/users/29242/codingpeon/) on 2018-02-24**:
I've opened an issue:
https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1334